# R sum instances where a date falls within any of the data ranges in df2

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two df.

1. 't_dates' has sequence of dates.
2. 'client_for_gg' has client_id and a start and end date for each client.

The output would tell me for each day in my t_dates$date how many clients had that date fall within their start and end date.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

t_dates <- seq.Date(from = as.Date('2022-11-01'),
                  to = as.Date('2022-11-15'),
                  by = "day")  %>%
  data.frame(date = .)

client_for_gg <- data.frame(client_id = c("x_555", "x_666", "x_777", "x_888", "x_999")
                            , start = c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-11-05", "2022-11-07", "2022-11-10")
                            , end = c("2022-11-03", "2022-11-12", "2022-12-01", "2022-12-01", "2022-12-01")) %>% 
  mutate(start = as.Date(start)
         , end = as.Date(end))

df <- t_dates %>% 
  mutate(count = sum(as.Date(t_dates$date) %within%
                       lubridate::interval(client_for_gg$start, client_for_gg$end)))
```

However, in my output my counts all come to 10 on each day.  Please help - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

client_for_gg %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(count = sum(t_dates$date >= start & t_dates$date <= end ))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  client_id start      end        count
  <chr>     <date>     <date>     <int>
1 x_555     2022-01-01 2022-11-03     3
2 x_666     2022-01-01 2022-11-12    12
3 x_777     2022-11-05 2022-12-01    11
4 x_888     2022-11-07 2022-12-01     9
5 x_999     2022-11-10 2022-12-01     6
```

Comment: Thanks VF, but I need the output to be all the days in t_dates and the sum to be of how many times a client has that data in their start and end range.

Comment: Sorry, you can apply the same logic, justng inverting the data.frames

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
> t_dates %>% 
+   rowwise() %>% 
+   mutate(count = sum(client_for_gg$start <= date & client_for_gg$end >= date))
# A tibble: 15 x 2
# Rowwise: 
   date       count
   <date>     <int>
 1 2022-11-01     2
 2 2022-11-02     2
 3 2022-11-03     2
 4 2022-11-04     1
 5 2022-11-05     2
 6 2022-11-06     2
 7 2022-11-07     3
 8 2022-11-08     3
 9 2022-11-09     3
10 2022-11-10     4
11 2022-11-11     4
12 2022-11-12     4
13 2022-11-13     3
14 2022-11-14     3
15 2022-11-15     3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(client_for_gg)[setDT(t_dates)[,d:=date], on =.(start<=d, end>=d)][, .N, date]
```

Output:

```
          date N
 1: 2022-11-01 2
 2: 2022-11-02 2
 3: 2022-11-03 2
 4: 2022-11-04 1
 5: 2022-11-05 2
 6: 2022-11-06 2
 7: 2022-11-07 3
 8: 2022-11-08 3
 9: 2022-11-09 3
10: 2022-11-10 4
11: 2022-11-11 4
12: 2022-11-12 4
13: 2022-11-13 3
14: 2022-11-14 3
15: 2022-11-15 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `devel` version of `dplyr`, we can use `join_by` which can also do non-equi joins

```
library(dplyr)
t_dates %>% 
  full_join(client_for_gg, by =join_by(date >= start, date <= end)) %>% 
  count(client_id, start, end, name = 'count')
```

-output

```
   client_id      start        end count
1     x_555 2022-01-01 2022-11-03     3
2     x_666 2022-01-01 2022-11-12    12
3     x_777 2022-11-05 2022-12-01    11
4     x_888 2022-11-07 2022-12-01     9
5     x_999 2022-11-10 2022-12-01     6
```